# *some* magento links pointing to old domain

Tags: magento, hyperlink, migration, product

I have just moved a magento site from one domain to the new one. Steps so far...

Backup the database and restore the database on the new domain. Change the core_config_base table for secure and unsecure base urls

Upload source files

Update the local.xml with new database information

Cleared cache

Now I can go to the site and everything is showing up fine on the new domain. The main navigation is working as it should. When I click on a product, however, it goes to the old domain. Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: FIXED IT!  I managed to get it fixed and thought I would share what I did. After much consideration I realized that all the images and links that were pointing to the old domain were on static pages. I did some digging and realized that everything was hard coded in the HTML of the content pages of the site. I've since gone in and edited those pages and now everything is working properly.  Edited to Add: I don't have the option to close this thread so if someone does please do so.

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify the links when you hover products are correct or in correct consistently? Is old base URL in all links I mean. Also check htaccess file for any directives containing the old domain. Also check to make sure no custom URL rewrites exist in the Magento admin Catalog → URL Rewrite Management .Once you verify htaccess or custom URL rewrites in Magento admin are not causing it, I can suggest other procedures to fix.

Comment: Hi LAMAGENTO. Thank you for your response. The only links that are displaying the problem are the actual products on the page. The main navigation continues to stay on the new domain. I have checked all the htaccess files. Some were still showing the old domain and I have updated them with the new one. The problem persists. I've looked in the URL Rewrite Management and all the url rewrites are relative paths.

Comment: oops hit enter too soon.  When I hover over the product links it shows the old domain as the target link. I'm thinking that something may be hard coded into the products page but don't know where to find it. The magento installation is quite large. I've looked but still have no idea where it might be. The site itself is quite large so when I try to do a search for the old domain in the folder my system locks up.

Comment: If you have local copy, simply install Sublime text editor. You can search all code in folder for occurrence of domain. Tar your site or FTP local copy. If you have SSH it's much faster to "grep -R domain.com " in the Magento root folder. Email me if you help. Lamagento@gmail.com

Comment: Hey LAMAGENTO, I've done a search for all instances of the old domain in directory and found a couple in the htaccess-bak and back ups of the old site map. There are also a lot int he blog but I'm not moving the blog... at least not yet. I'm going to send you a message via email now.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your previous developer didn't follow all Magento standards while coding.

My suggestion is download your code and search for strings that equates to your previous domain.Also check in data base, as use of CMS blocks too might result in previous domain links.

Comment: Did the search through the code for the previous domains. None of the results were related. i.e. from the blog (which is not being moved right now) and old back up files.

Answer (score 0):

Btw make sure you delete all caches

Rm -rf var/cache/*

Answer (score 0):

Verify base URL and secure URL are correct in all scopes via drop down in Magento system configuration.

Comment: Hey LAMAGENTO, I have cleared the var/cache and var/sessions. The base URL and Secure URLs are correct in all the scopes like you mentioned on Friday. I've also checked to make sure the display mode for all products is set to "products only". I'm still at a loss. There's GOT to be something in there making this happen but I can't seem to find it.